# Trigger click to activate typeahead after element gets focus

Tags: angularjs, onclick, focus, typeahead.js

Need help with several issues. Here is simplified code:

**HTML**

```
    <input type="text" title="{{e.Name}}" ng-model="e.modelName" ng-required="true" typeahead-editable="false" ng-blur="vm.isUnchanged(i)" focus-me="vm.Event"
own-typeahead typeahead-on-select="vm.changeValue($item, $model, $label, i)" 
uib-typeahead="$Event, $viewValue)" typeahead-min-length="0"/>
```

**JS**

```
app.directive("ownTypeahead", function() {
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            scope: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            require: ["ngModel"]
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {

            element.bind('click', function () {
                if (ctrls[0].$viewValue && ctrls[0].$viewValue == ' ') {
                    ctrls[0].$setViewValue('');
                }
                ctrls[0].$setViewValue(' ');
            });

            element.bind('focus', function () {
                if (!ctrls[0].$viewValue || ctrls[0].$viewValue == '') {
                    ctrls[0].$setViewValue(' ');
                }
            });
        }
    });


/**
 * Directive that places focus on the element it is applied to when the
 * expression it binds to evaluates to true
 */
app.directive('focusMe', ['$timeout', function focusMe($timeout) {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.focusMe, function (newVal) {
            if (newVal) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    elem[0].focus();
                }, 0, false);
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

The problems/questions are:

1) The main one. Focus after clicking on certain items triggers **typeahead** ddl  in the input field almost always, but there are several items that move focus but don't trigger the list to be opened. Any ideas where is the issue? (the code above works in about 90% of the cases and in 100% with a click on input field)

2) Not ideal solution, but an ok workaround could be trigger a **click** event on the focused input field to open the list. Can't manage to get that right the angular way. How this could be done?

Comment: `element.triggerHandler('click');`

Comment: isn't it jQuery? Plus I need the click only if focused and somehow prevent double clicking when user clicks himself.

Comment: angular's jqlite has it too.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element
you can pass params with the triggerHandler so you could just set a flag or something to prevent "double click" behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by adding a **200ms** timeout for the focusMe:

```
app.directive('focusMe', ['$timeout', function focusMe($timeout) {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.focusMe, function (newVal) {
            if (newVal) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    elem[0].focus();
                }, 200, false);
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

If anyone has better suggestions would accept the answer.